# Remove Resharper files from TFS

Tags: tfs, resharper

We have just added a new project to TFS.

The developer was using resharper. The resharper files were added to TFS automatically.

How can we remove these files from TFS? Or is it not a problem that they are there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Team Foundation Server's [Destroy Command](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386005.aspx).  This command is available only on the command line because it should rarely be used.  Normally, you'd just want to delete it from the project and still have history just in case, but in your situation, a permanent delete seems ok.  I would suggest you make a backup of the repository before you run this, just to be safe.

```
tf destroy [/keephistory] <itemspec1>[;<versionspec>][<itemspec2>...<itemspecN>] 
 [/stopat:<versionspec>] [/preview] [/startcleanup] [/noprompt] [/silent] [/login:username,[password]] [/collection:TeamProjectCollectionUrl]]
```

Comment: Also, to use the destroy command, you must belong to the Team Foundation Administrators security group.